# Euler-Poincaré-Characteristic of Polyhedra

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, polynomials, topology

Given a *triangulation* of the surface of a polyhedron `p`, calculate its Euler-Poincaré-Characteristic `χ(p) = V-E+F`, where `V` is the number of vertices, `E` the number of edges and `F` the number of faces.

#### Details

The vertices are enumerated as `1,2,...,V`. The triangulation is given as a list, where each entry is a list of the vertices of one face, given in clockwise or counterclockwise order.

Despite the name, the triangulation can also contain faces with more than 3 sides. The faces can assumed to be simply connected that means that the boundary of each faces can be drawn using one closed non-self-intersecting loop.

#### Examples

**Tetrahedron**: This tetrahedron is convex and has `χ = 2`. A possible triangulation is

```
[[1,2,3], [1,3,4], [1,2,4], [2,3,4]]
```

[image]

**Cube**: This cube is convex and has `χ = 2`. A possible triangulation is

```
[[1,2,3,4], [1,4,8,5], [1,2,6,5], [2,3,7,6], [4,3,7,8],  [5,6,7,8]]
```

[image]

**Donut**: This donut/toroid shape has `χ = 0`. A possible triangulation is

```
[[1,2,5,4], [2,5,6,3], [1,3,6,4], [1,2,7,9], [2,3,8,7], [1,9,8,3], [4,9,8,6], [4,5,7,9], [5,7,8,6]]
```

[image]

**Double Donut**: This double-donut should have `χ = -2`. It is constructed by using two copies of the donut above and identifying the sides `[1,2,5,4]` of the first one with the side `[1,3,6,4]` of the second one.

```
[[2,5,6,3], [1,3,6,4], [1,2,7,9], [2,3,8,7], [1,9,8,3], [4,9,8,6], [4,5,7,9], [5,7,8,6], [1,10,11,4], [10,11,5,2], [1,10,12,14], [10,2,13,12], [1,14,13,2], [4,14,13,5], [4,11,12,14], [11,12,13,5]]
```

(Examples verified using [this Haskell program](https://tio.run/##tVPLTsMwELz7K/ZQiURsEUmTviS4UA5IHLlFFnKLaSLStEocaL@@rB95NCpHcvHs7sys145TUX3JPD@fs91hXypYCSXuXrNKMfYpNrKC5RKS5KVQnMP4EQi4vCozeIBcFluV6oCxb1mq7LqkLfVVo6Jewwg2@2IjlLWQH9urepsfikdWOoKdOIDe1dv@uSEy@EllKS/S3nF5rHyy8CoaNTliLioFx4r7sOwTbxyTgf2GpdPA5sT9of70pz555yRNOGObNLsyqs7aQS8ObQzdGdxCewV0ZEQ7qTQrtk7mOQf0@gbY6bGT@z5j6k2qUug9JQGGOOEIBCYYWRBaEJoMZ@qpXsuO3LAinGPcCKYW6vIMpxpGBs4JQhJTXWPyWu2LWrVmcdNJM9ptTLuNzHDR@M5xZrMLghPbQkPXLW64GuisaVavc9m1/Jc@hhvcYxA4OwNjDLtKiEFTIjihhKtFOgqtsQ1iFwQ9lcW6Rr8Q24msoGkOZVYoekvmJfT@iMReLoK5NlrM@GZtD4Oz8/kX).)

Comment: Can different faces have different numbers of vertices?

Comment: Yes, they can have any number of vertices.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

```hs
f m=maximum(id=<<m)-sum[0.5|_:_:l<-m,x<-l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY3NasMwEITvfgodemhhHaI/2wnWkwgRDE2oqTeEWoEc@u7urn6avkAPgm9nRjMf0/p5XpZtuwh0OD1mvOPr/O7GEd/a9Y5@v7Pfp@PpuIwtwmNsl7BF6byXoEAHEAQaTAaVQSUlNFHVXA0YGMDWbJeR7R46RpNwIBTeks9MNbrU2FrP3u9291zv4VAbB@izeiDUuZyx7NiaZWCVZgzN/Et3yso9SFnqElpQT0eBrBahJqF4hi@Vi/NhyyH//MrMXmiaeF7jKpzwUYKIip6mZ0KD03x1t6/5Gl9wuomLSMntBw)

Combines the face and edge terms by subtracting 0.5 for every edge on a face beyond the first two.

Alt 42 bytes:

```hs
f m=maximum(id=<<m)-sum(0.5<$(drop 2=<<m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY1LjsIwEET3OUUvWIDUg3DbToIUnyTKIhIgosEQESPN7TPd/gxzARaWXleVq67j8n2@3db1At758WfyL7@dTq7r/O5rYT7sbbfZnp6PGSiquzUo1/cKCfWAwKDRJKAEFJWhClRyJWCwRVuydUKxG6wFTcSWEXrLvjDX6FxjS714f9v1e73BY2lssUnqkVGncsG8Y0tWQFSeMTzzke6YVQdUKtdFtEhvh1AVi1GzkD0jF6XidNh8qH@/Eos3VFU4L2EBB31QCIH4aX5mqPw43d38nO5h48cZLhCT6y8)

Comment: This is very clever :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>49</s> 46 bytes

```hs
u=length
f x|j<-x>>=id=maximum j+u x-u j`div`2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v9Q2JzUvvSSDK02hoibLRrfCzs42M8U2N7EiM7c0VyFLu1ShQrdUISshJbMsweh/bmJmnm1BUWZeiUpadLShjpGOcayOApBhrGMCYRhBGEZgkdj/AA)

I get the number of vertices by concating the faces and finding the maximum.  I find the number of faces by taking the length.  I find the number of edges by summing the lengths of the faces and dividing by 2.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18</s> <s>17</s> <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

*1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer, and 1 more for telling me about `Ɗ`.*

```
FṀ_FLHƊ+L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcy9EYMwDAXgVejziki2@VmAo/AGPi5VGo4F6FKzURbIHkwiZMsc6T69J2l5r@smMh7fz2uM029/RBFJiRHQws1oEsEpvZHRYchkTXt0lg7KsusLW2O4djNqSqAniOq7wgC@GwZdldJpUDufJ7bHNoQ60N@VOXfzCQ)

Uses the actually intelligent not-hacked-together solution everybody else is probably using. (Credit to [@totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158169/30164) for the only other solution I could understand enough to reimplement it.)

### Old solution (17 bytes)

```
ṙ€1FżFṢ€QL
;FQL_Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzpmPmtYYuh3d4/Zw5yIgM9CHy9ot0Cf@cPv///@jo410THXMdIxjdRSiDXWMgUwTCNNIx1zHEsQ0Aopa6JhDRC2BTLBaEzDTDMI0hakFMaCihjqGBjqGhlDjwExTHSOEjJGOIUwKyDQGCkDlTEA8I4jBEI4plGOIpAvCBsnFAgA)

I hope I got everything right. Assumes that all faces contain at least 3 vertices and that no two faces have the same vertices; I'm not good enough in topology to come up with something that breaks the code.

Alternative 17 byte solution:

```
ṙ€1FżFṢ€,;F$QL$€I
```

#### Explanation

```
;FQL_Ç    Main link. Argument: faces
            e.g. [[1,2,3],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[2,3,4]]
 F          Flatten the list. We now have a flat list of vertices.
            e.g. [1,2,3,1,3,4,1,2,4,2,3,4]
;           Append this to the original list.
            e.g. [[1,2,3],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[2,3,4],1,2,3,1,3,4,1,2,4,2,3,4]
  Q         Remove duplicates. We now have a list of faces and vertices.
            e.g. [[1,2,3],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[2,3,4],1,2,3,4]
   L        Get the length of this list. This is equal to V+F.
            e.g. 8
     Ç      Call the helper link on the faces to get E.
            e.g. 6
    _       Subtract the edges from the previous result to get V-E+F.
            e.g. 2

ṙ€1FżFṢ€QL    Helper link. Argument: faces
                e.g. [[1,2,3],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[2,3,4]]
ṙ€1             Rotate each face 1 position to the left.
                e.g. [[2,3,1],[3,4,1],[2,4,1],[3,4,2]]
   F            Flatten this result.
                e.g. [2,3,1,3,4,1,2,4,1,3,4,2]
     F          Flatten the original faces.
                e.g. [1,2,3,1,3,4,1,2,4,2,3,4]
    ż           Pair the items of the two flattened lists.
                e.g. [[2,1],[3,2],[1,3],[3,1],[4,3],[1,4],[2,1],[4,2],[1,4],[3,2],[4,3],[2,4]]
      Ṣ€        Order each edge.
                e.g. [[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],[1,3],[3,4],[1,4],[1,2],[2,4],[1,4],[2,3],[3,4],[2,4]]
        Q       Remove duplicates. We now have a list of edges.
                e.g. [[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],[3,4],[1,4],[2,4]]
         L      Get the length of the list to get E.
                e.g. 6
```

Comment: Can't you replace `;/` with `F`? ;-)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Lol, that was apparently left there as some kind of brainfart from a dev version

Comment: In fact, it made the code error in case of empty arrays.

Comment: Will there ever be empty arrays?

Comment: Oh, and 1) your TIO link has a different code and 2) [there are new quicks!](https://tio.run/##Tcy9EYMwDAXgVejziki2@VmAo/AGPi5VGo4F6FKzURbIHkwiZMsc6T69J2l5r@smMh7fz2uM029/RBFJiRHQws1oEsEpvZHRYchkTXt0lg7KsusLW2O4djNqSqAniOq7wgC@GwZdldJpUDufJ7bHNoQ60N@VOXfzCQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
⌈/∘∊+≢-2÷⍨≢∘∊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY09boNAEEZ7n2I6QBYyu7D8@DbIERYKEhamsSx3VkScEKWJlDqVu1RRpJTxTeYieGYHcwI3zJs3H9/mm8p/2OVVvfZXVb7dlqsB3z7KGp/eg6GgL752C@w@sTvN8fnL15df7M9E4oahpcwe@x9SDWGB/d/SKfKycojIN/hydOpH5zBzFWgIPRohRJ7daGi7taDHu5wiSMFIJmbgQwKx50YWUs81dGCY/jTSxn58JL49k0AmFSkkbDKCkLsYbKmRDA82LQSze3VRRgWglC2wYEDfrAYlmiCk1fqIWXOVoLGoprQQ@xb@v/UV)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to... user56656 (was Wheat Wizard originally).*

```python
lambda l:len(l)-len(sum(l,[]))/2+max(sum(l,[]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYtNDoIwGET3nGISN622MRYXhoSlHoENuqjwVUhKIaX4cwKP55FQdGNYzcubme4RqtapcQG5lCjasnaXBEMwcjeZKFrg9WQdR4pM7lcHgVtFnpCh7hEqghuaM3m0BlfyoS6oF9jPGiov1EO7EodZY/TnEEUmPY5WN@dSwyaWHLNcTtEPDbMiP3G@VqtG3//E2PnaBWZYnm@EEvFJ4AOx2P5A/UB9zTR/Aw)

Comment: I improved my original haskell answer by saving `sum(l,[])` to be used twice.  I don't know if this could be used in Python as well.

Comment: @user56656 It indeed saves a byte, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 29 bytes

This one is tailor made for the perl `-a` option which does almost all the work already

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -a
@V[@F]=$e+=@F}{say$#V+$.-$e/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYs/D4IwEMX3foqX2I2AvWsLMpAwsbmyGAcGBhMjRFyM8atb76rL/d6fe@t8v8aU@vHUD@fOzkXXD@/XNj3tbixsVdp5zykxImp4Q/DCIGQ0aA2LP6AR3wq9CZm1MOZer3oCORDpMjOCDQX8YtaQQT5LaO6lD38V9TPoSmu9Of0s6@Oy3LZUTqk8xopc5b4)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att).

```
Max@#-Tr[Tr/@(1^#)/2-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY5LCoMwEIavMhiQFiI2MfGxaPEChS7ciYVQKnVhF@KiIJ49zbPRC3QRmG/mn/kyivn1HMU8PITs4QzyKj41Spqpbaa0PpA7OqY0IV0sb9PwnluEIYLkAhGGvkVdBzGkNSzLQjBQDNmKQZcZBuZK6krqurr26ZBiGEoMPOzkjmysUA1NzFOpiZuYoc1VHoQ2sPlUvvuX2qyCQ/kLN6sMZc5oyft52LOlmRn/X412j5zUI97hQKXodq5s5BfQkOmmTzDboM7mmXsmuwueTGJd5Rc)

Comment: 24: `Max@#-Tr[Tr/@(1^#)/2-1]&`

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÑF4╨Ω◙╜#├
```

[Run and debug online](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a54634d0ea0abd23c3&i=[[1,2,3],+[1,3,4],+[1,2,4],+[2,3,4]]%0A[[1,2,3,4],+[1,4,8,5],+[1,2,6,5],+[2,3,7,6],+[4,3,7,8],++[5,6,7,8]]%0A[[1,2,5,4],+[2,5,6,3],+[1,3,6,4],+[1,2,7,9],+[2,3,8,7],+[1,9,8,3],+[4,9,8,6],+[4,5,7,9],+[5,7,8,6]]%0A[[2,5,6,3],+[1,3,6,4],+[1,2,7,9],+[2,3,8,7],+[1,9,8,3],+[4,9,8,6],+[4,5,7,9],+[5,7,8,6],+[1,10,11,4],+[10,11,5,2],+[1,10,12,14],+[10,2,13,12],+[1,14,13,2],+[4,14,13,5],+[4,11,12,14],+[11,12,13,5]]&a=1&m=2)

It's a straight-forward port of totallyhuman's [python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158169/527).

```
%   length of input (a)
x$Y flatten input and store in y
%h  half of flattened length (b)
-   subtract a - b (c)
y|M maximum value in y (d)
+   add c + d and output
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%25%09length+of+input+%28a%29%0Ax%24Y%09flatten+input+and+store+in+y%0A%25h%09half+of+flattened+length+%28b%29%0A-%09subtract+a+-+b+%28c%29%0Ay%7CM%09maximum+value+in+y+%28d%29%0A%2B%09add+c+%2B+d+and+output&i=[[1,2,3],+[1,3,4],+[1,2,4],+[2,3,4]]%0A[[1,2,3,4],+[1,4,8,5],+[1,2,6,5],+[2,3,7,6],+[4,3,7,8],++[5,6,7,8]]%0A[[1,2,5,4],+[2,5,6,3],+[1,3,6,4],+[1,2,7,9],+[2,3,8,7],+[1,9,8,3],+[4,9,8,6],+[4,5,7,9],+[5,7,8,6]]%0A[[2,5,6,3],+[1,3,6,4],+[1,2,7,9],+[2,3,8,7],+[1,9,8,3],+[4,9,8,6],+[4,5,7,9],+[5,7,8,6],+[1,10,11,4],+[10,11,5,2],+[1,10,12,14],+[10,2,13,12],+[1,14,13,2],+[4,14,13,5],+[4,11,12,14],+[11,12,13,5]]&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 28 bytes

```
x->#x+#Set(y=concat(x))-#y/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY09DoMwDEavEsECqqM2gfAzwCU6IgaESlWpohFiCKencZxAL9Dt2e/zZz0sL/7U@8QathvexuYS3x9rsjXjZx6HNTFpyuPtKvdB6/eWGMZbppfXbA2LcIjYhCFgXdcJkJD1FgVkkBNIAuk2SJQKOocKVEgWhKhLKBBzhxWishrx6FChGc3xtjgfl1CHugpK2tYWM2pG9E9UyCLg1j35S7PLihsI4escKpCnkSCCspjZhXc5TpKKaVB@ED9XxOj6Pt2/)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ZsgI˜g;-+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TczBDYMwDAXQVbjzkbAThyImYIVGHKhUZQDWYSOGSp04iN6e/7c9yv6hb87vI63XmZahzzlGhiDAbegiwSm9kTFhLmRNX5gsnZV111cGo9y7BS0l0Aii9q5SwE/DoLtSOg1a58vE9tgGaQP9XZlLt/0A)

**Explanation**

```
Z          # push number of vertices (V)
 sg        # push number of faces (F)
   I˜g;    # push number of edges (E)
       -   # subtract (F-E)
        +  # add (F-E+V)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 12 bytes

```
+-eSsQ/lsQ2l
```

**[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B-eSsQ%2FlsQ2l&input=%5B%5B2%2C5%2C6%2C3%5D%2C+%5B1%2C3%2C6%2C4%5D%2C+%5B1%2C2%2C7%2C9%5D%2C+%5B2%2C3%2C8%2C7%5D%2C+%5B1%2C9%2C8%2C3%5D%2C+%5B4%2C9%2C8%2C6%5D%2C+%5B4%2C5%2C7%2C9%5D%2C+%5B5%2C7%2C8%2C6%5D%2C+%5B1%2C10%2C11%2C4%5D%2C+%5B10%2C11%2C5%2C2%5D%2C+%5B1%2C10%2C12%2C14%5D%2C+%5B10%2C2%2C13%2C12%5D%2C+%5B1%2C14%2C13%2C2%5D%2C+%5B4%2C14%2C13%2C5%5D%2C+%5B4%2C11%2C12%2C14%5D%2C+%5B11%2C12%2C13%2C5%5D%5D&debug=0)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 46 bytes

A port of [@Wheat Wizard♦'s Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158165/110802) in Scala.

---

```scala
x=>{val j=x.flatten;j.max+x.length-j.length/2}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RYwxDoJAEEV7TjElxAUjWBjMmliaaGWsDMWIu8hmXQ2MBmM8iQ0Wegav4m3ElYRm_rw_f_79VaaoMao_78NGiZRggbmBqwOwFRL2DbhYZGUM06LAy3pJRW6yxIthZXICbpMAZ9SwRcLGmOcluXYMWMgij0ELERt2EHYQ2otne45NO2njSvfXZs2b49h6Gdv42o6ZoSThk0aAP08k_dEnqPjk-gsqXgVSI5EwYxXssepVgRYmo52v2qUf3v5fj1br-q9f)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 22 bytes

```
{(#x)+(|/y)--2!#y}/,/\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJytkE0SwiAMhfecAqcbGGUo4a81V3HdM9hR724SaF3pxrLJFx7wXliuDzPc7dk8/Wqdg9OwvvzF35RajAkIGC1SjZikglSQ3mqvQR++duNumXDC3M2LEGsVC1ESmogyaUx/hNqMc5+Rn9ymL/v8FeceYcIqezNRlDBMLVbu57jyHscafxkfa8fnwoiBfs8qrU3jjLArgEEsRvIIkfqmJG5A3mycG4fPjYas8FDu+2erN7LubE8=)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

```js
a=>a.map(b=>(v=Math.max(v,...b),d+=b.length/2-1),d=v=0)&&v-d
```

Explanation: Loops over each face, keeping track of the largest vertex seen in `v` and tracking the number of edges minus the number of faces in `d` as per @xnor's answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.size+a.flatten!.max-a.size/2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY7JDsIwDETvfEU54xaydTnAj0Q5BKmVkAAh2kos4ttDHCe0cOf2PDP2@Dru767bunxnn7boD492ZYvuaIehPS@Lk73lpK75y13Goc86rTUDDsJA5kGAJOAEPCjGLL7DKSWhBpUWSkK0KygRZcDaY6aV95F/b6lUhIHPF@X0RwVNOltDRWrjUVADYixTKYuA6rzrLwUhyzbAWDwXUAGfHA4sWR6FF6InceJ0mAYVBzbbIkbPGPcG)

Answer (score 0):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 35 bytes

```py
l=>max(f=sum(l,[]))-len(f)/2+len(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/H1i43sUIjzba4NFcjRyc6VlNTNyc1TyNNU99IG8TI0fxfUJSZV6KRphEdbahjpGMcq6MAZBjrmEAYRhCGEVgEqP0/AA)